# RegEx for capturing part of a string

Tags: python, regex, markdown, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I am trying to grab top level Markdown headings (i.e., headings beginning with a single hash -- # Introduction) in an .md doc with Python's re library and cannot for the life of me figure this out.

Here is the code I'm trying to execute:

```
import re

pattern = r"(# .+?\\n)"

text = r"# Title\n## Chapter\n### sub-chapter#### What a lovely day.\n"

header = re.search(pattern, text)
print(header.string)
```

The result from the `print(header.string)` is:

`# Title\n## Chapter\n### sub-chapter#### What a lovely day.\n` whereas I only want `# Title\n`

This example on regex101 says it should work, but I can't figure out why it isn't. https://regex101.com/r/u4ZIE0/9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get that result because you use `header.string` which is calling [.string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.string) on a [Match object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) which will give you back the string passed to `match()` or search`()`.

The string already has newlines in it:

```
text = r"# Title\n## Chapter\n### sub-chapter#### What a lovely day.\n"
```

So if you use your pattern (note that it will also match the newline), you could update your code to:

```
import re

pattern = r"(# .+?\\n)"
text = r"# Title\n## Chapter\n### sub-chapter#### What a lovely day.\n"
header = re.search(pattern, text)
print(header.group())
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/b9MdBu)

Note that [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) looks for the first location where the regex produces a match.

Another option to match your value could be matching from the start of the string a `#` followed by a space and then any character except a newline until the end of the string:

```
^# .*$
```

For example:

```
import re

pattern = r"^# .*$"
text = "# Title\n## Chapter\n### sub-chapter#### What a lovely day.\n"
header = re.search(pattern, text, re.M)
print(header.group())
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/mI9H4P)

If there can not be any more `#` following after, you might also use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) to match not a `#` or a newline:

```
^# [^#\n\r]+$
```

Comment: Ugh -- this was it!  If I had just done `print(header)` I would have seen that it was matching correctly.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that we are wishing to extract the `# Title\n`, which in that case, your expression seems to be working fine with a slight modification:

```
(# .+?\\n)(.+)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/s09M0A/1)

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(# .+?\\n)(.+)"

test_str = "# Title\\n## Chapter\\n### sub-chapter#### The Bar\\nIt was a fall day.\\n"

subst = "\\1"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 1)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```